# Xcart error caused by sql syntax

Tags: mysql, error-handling, x-cart

I am running my store under Xcart and I get following error on top of web browser:

```
INVALID SQL: 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=1073741824' at line 1
SQL QUERY FAILURE:SET OPTION SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=1073741824
INVALID SQL: 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1' at line 1
SQL QUERY FAILURE:SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1
INVALID SQL: 1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1' at line 1
SQL QUERY FAILURE:SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1
```

what cause this so I can clear the error?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your MySQL server has been updated.

Replace all strings like 
`'SET OPTION SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE'` 
to these
`'SET SESSION MAX_JOIN_SIZE'`

A command for the unix-based hostings

`sed -i  's/SET OPTION /SET SESSION /' $(grep --include='*.php' -rl 'SET OPTION ' ~/www/xcart_4_6_x)`

Comment: and how do I replace those strings? do I just need mysql query?

Comment: You have to changed php files.

Comment: `sed -i  's/SET OPTION /SET SESSION /' `grep --include='*.php' -rl 'SET OPTION ' ~/www/xcart_4_6_x``

Answer (score 0):

It needs to check the xcart php scripts where this query is executed and `OPTION` to be replaced with `SESSION` for the errors like

> SQL QUERY FAILURE:SET OPTION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1

Also, as for

> SQL QUERY FAILURE:SET OPTION SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE=1073741824

it might worth to change it just to `db_query("SET max_join_size=1073741824");`

It works for some xcart installations so please report if it helps to your project as well, thanks